# Link another table based on a column value

Tags: mysql, orm, entity-attribute-value

[image]

Hi, I'm designing a item catalog using MySQL and Squalize ORM (NodeJS).

Suppose I have a product list with different attributes based on its category (`attributes_id` in this case).
I would like to get a product by using a JOIN statement with an appropriate attribute table. The design should be scalable as we will have more than a hundred attribute tables.

Roughly the statement will look like this:

```
 JOIN
   if ( product.attributes_id == 1 ) 'attributes_car'
   elseif ( product.attributes_id == 2 ) 'attributes_food'
```

BUT the the number of `elseif` cases will grow more than a hundred later.

So the question is how to design `attributes_id`? Is it a good idea to make it a foreign key to the database metadata (like INFORMATION_SCHEMA) to point to another table? Should I introduce another table to manage such relationship?

One of option is a Dynamic SQL but I don't think it is a good idea because the `ifelse` cases should grow.

Or should I give up designing a query and just implement such logic on NodeJS side using ORM?

Thank you!

Comment: [EAV models](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav) aren't a particularly strong suite for SQL.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create an additional table that stores `attribute_id` and `table_name`.

```
    Create table attibute_tablename(
    attribute_id int(11),
    table_name varchar(25),
    PRIMARY KEY (attribute_id, table_name)
    )
```

You can also add a foreign key to the `product` table if you want. 
Then you only need an insert to this table for every new item added